# What are the HTML5 elements I should be using to build a front-end menu?

Tags: css

I know that HTML5 provides menu elements to do this but I can't remember what they are.

Is there a good reference for HTML5 elements that had readability?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, are you referring to html5 elements (like `<nav>`)?

Comment: CSS doesn't provide _any_ 'elements'. Please learn the distinction between front-end technologies.

Comment: I believe you mean HTML, and that would the the `<nav>` element, usually combined with `<ul>` and `<li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean HTML, and that would the the `<nav>` element, usually combined with `<ul>` and `<li>`.  Like:

```css
body {
  background-color: #EBE8E4;
  color: #222;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 15px;
}
nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  color: #888;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 22px 8px 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
nav > ul > li > a > .caret,
nav > ul > li > ul > li > a > .caret {
  border-top: 4px solid #aaa;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: color 0.1s linear;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li > a > .caret {
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid #f2f2f2;
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
  color: #aaa;
  display: block;
  line-height: 56px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(40, 44, 47);
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a > .caret {
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
nav > ul > li > div ul > li:hover > a > .caret {
  border-left-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
nav > ul > li > ul,
nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
  background-color: rgb(40, 44, 47);
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 165px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
  background-color: rgb(40, 44, 47);
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  margin-top: -42px;
  right: -165px;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul,
nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li,
nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li > a,
nav > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li:hover > a {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Menu 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Sub Menu 1-1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>Sub Menu 1-2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: CSS was mostly taken from http://www.adam-bray.com/blog/91/easy-html-5-css-3-navigation-menu/ with some minor modifications to remove unnecessary divs for sub-menus.

Comment: I'd like to use the nav-uk-li paradigm w/ out the a element as I don't need to "link out".  I'm planning on using a `span` instead of the a.  It works well so far.